# Tail recursiveness in Scala methods with multiple parameter lists

Tags: scala

I have the following function:

```
  @tailrec
  def samePrefix[A](length: Int)(a: Vector[A], b: Vector[A]): Boolean = {
    if(length<1) true
    else{
      if(a(length-1)==b(length-1)) samePrefix(length-1)(a, b)
      else false
    }
  }
```

which checks if two vectors have equal first elements, given a length to check.

I was wondering if the part that calls

```
samePrefix(length-1)(a, b)
```

would first create a function object from `samePrefix(length-1)` and then apply `(a,b)` to it, or if it would just call my method tail-recursively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see...

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.1
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.annotation._
import scala.annotation._

scala> @tailrec def curried(a: Int)(b: Int): Int = curried(a-1)(b-1)
curried: (a: Int)(b: Int)Int

scala> :javap curried
  ... irrelevant output removed ...       

  public int curried(int, int);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=3, args_size=3
         0: iload_1       
         1: iconst_1      
         2: isub          
         3: iload_2       
         4: iconst_1      
         5: isub          
         6: istore_2      
         7: istore_1      
         8: goto          0

  ... irrelevant output removed ...
```

As you can see, there is no recursive invocation in the bytecode. Instead, there is a `goto 0` instruction which indicates a loop. This means that tail call optimization has taken place.

You'll also notice that multiple parameter lists have been squashed into a single parameter list in the compiled bytecode, so there are no intermediate functions involved.

**EDIT**: Actually, we didn't really have to inspect bytecode to be 100% sure that the method has been compiled with TCO, because `@tailrec` annotation exists exactly for that purpose. In other words, if you put `@tailrec` on your method and it compiles without errors, you can be 100% sure that it has been compiled with TCO.

Comment: Thanks. I think I should start learning how to interpret Java bytecode.